# Can I control Input Type by Field?

Tags: 7, entities, input-formats

I have a node type with multiple text fields. The majority of these are designed to fit very specific templates, and have fixed height and width, and are generally quite small.  The full CKE interface is too much of a good thing for these fields, so I made a different "Text Format," and tied it to a distinct Wysiwyg profile, "Full HTML (Simple)"

All of this is super, except that the default is still the default, and unless the user CHOOSES the other profile... it serves no purpose whatsoever.  These same users have access to multiple filters, so the obvious option is out.

I understand limiting the profiles by roles... and I half understand [Filtering by Node Type](http://drupal.org/project/filterbynodetype)... but I don't understand not limiting them by field.

I checked modules and it looks like [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) is on the way to doing it for 7, but I can't see any modules out there that ready for prime time.

I can't be the first person who has desired this.  Is there a hiccup in my logic, or a methodology I should be considering?

Comment: I use Better Formats in dozens of Drupal 7 production sites - no problems so far

Comment: Excellent... I'll give that a try and see if it can do what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Clive was spot on... Better Formats does exactly what I wanted.